# Svelte API loads multiple times and keeps old data

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

**Initial note**: this is an `ssr = false` project and I cannot/do not use server data, all API calls are made with `axios` inside pages/components. I removed as much code as I could to keep only what matters.

I have a `<Feed />` component:

```js
<script>
    import Post from '$lib/components/post/Post.svelte';
    import InfiniteScroll from '$lib/components/structure/InfiniteScroll.svelte';
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
    import { api } from '$lib/utils/api';

    import { onMount} from 'svelte';

    export let args = {};

    let currentPage = 1;
    let data = [];
    let newBatch = [];

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    async function fetchData() {
        await api.post.index(currentPage, args)
            .then((response) => {
                newBatch = response.data.data;
            })
    }

    onMount(() => {
        fetchData();
    });

    $: data = [...data, ...newBatch];
</script>

    {#each data as post}
        <Post {post} />
    {/each}

    <!-- No more items -->
    {#if newBatch.length}
        <InfiniteScroll
            hasMore={newBatch.length}
            threshold={100}
            on:loadMore={() => {
                currentPage++;
                fetchData();
            }}
        />
    {:else}
        <p class="mt-5 text-gray-400 text-center">No more posts.</p>
    {/if}
```

This is the skeleton for `<InfiniteScroll />`:

```js
<script>
    import { Preloader } from 'konsta/svelte';
    import { onDestroy, createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    export let threshold = 0;
    export let horizontal = false;
    // export let elementScroll;
    let elementScroll;
    export let hasMore = true;

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    let isLoadMore = false;
    let component;

    $: {
        if (component || elementScroll) {
            const element = elementScroll ? elementScroll : component.parentNode;

            element.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
            element.addEventListener('resize', onScroll);
        }
    }

    const onScroll = (e) => {
        const element = e.target;

        const offset = horizontal
            ? e.target.scrollWidth - e.target.clientWidth - e.target.scrollLeft
            : e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.clientHeight - e.target.scrollTop;

        if (offset <= threshold) {
            if (!isLoadMore && hasMore) {
                dispatch('loadMore');
            }
            isLoadMore = true;
        } else {
            isLoadMore = false;
        }
    };

    onDestroy(() => {
        if (component || elementScroll) {
            const element = elementScroll ? elementScroll : component.parentNode;

            element.removeEventListener('scroll', null);
            element.removeEventListener('resize', null);
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="text-center mx-auto">
    <Preloader class="mt-4" colors={{ iconIos: 'text-primary' }} size="w-8 h-8" />
</div>
<div bind:this={component} style="width:0px" />
```

Then I have a `user/[slug]/+page.svelte` page where I load the profile data and the profile posts based on the user slug.

```js
<script>
    import ProfileImage from '$lib/components/ProfileImage.svelte';
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import Feed from '$lib/components/post/Feed.svelte';
    import { api } from '$lib/utils/api';

    export let userSlug = null;
    export let ownProfile = null;
    let loading = true;
    let user = { data: { user: {}, friends: [], friendship: null } };
    let friendship = null;

    $: {
        fetchData($page.params.slug);
    }

    async function fetchData(slug) {
        loading = true;
        userSlug = ownProfile ? null : slug;
        user = await api.user.show(userSlug).finally(() => {
            loading = false;
        });
        friendship = user.data.friendship;
    }
</script>

<div class="w-1/3 mx-auto">
    <ProfileImage user={user.data.user} size="w-full" link={false} />
</div>

<h1 class="text-center font-bold text-xl">
    {user.data.user.full_name || '-'}
</h1>

{#key userSlug}
    <Feed
        args={{ user_slug: userSlug }}
    />
{/key}
```

From within this page I can visit different profiles, and this caused the data not to reload (ie: changed from `user/profile-a` to `user/profile-b`, the data was still from `profile a`) so I used `$: { fetchData($page.params.slug) }` which hopefully is the right strategy.
But is probably what is now causing this issue:

When I scroll to the bottom, the `<InfiniteScroll/>`  inside `<Feed/>` loads more posts, but as you can see from this video: https://imgur.com/a/tpVTMDd, when I visit Profile A, then Profile B, then Profile C and I scroll down to the bottom, the `<InfiniteScroll/>` fires and calls the API of **all** profiles I visited and keeps in memory all the data running multiple API calls instead of the current profile only.

I think I have to do "destroy" of the element probably but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the event handler to `removeEventListener`, currently you are passing `null`.

Also, you add listeners in a reactive block, I would highly recommend not doing that, as you might unexpectedly add more than one listener. If there is some conditional logic for determining the element to watch, do that *once* so you can be sure that listeners are only ever added to and removed from said element.

Comment: I see, so in this case I should pass `onScroll`. By doing that the issue solves!

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth creating a small Sveltekit repo on GitHub that actually reproduces the issues - but here's some potential problems and solutions:

## Raise `isLoadMore` to the `<Feed/>` component

(same as you have in the `+page.svelte`)

This fixes a potential issues where `loadMore` events have fired onScroll but handled at unexpected times because of the JS event loop.

```js
let isLoadMore = false;

async function fetchData() {
  if (isLoadMore) return;

  isLoadMore = true;
  await api.post.index(currentPage, args)
    .then((response) => {
      newBatch = response.data.data
    })
    .finally(() => (isLoadMore = false));

}
```

## Bind event listeners `svelte:window` in `<InfiniteScroll />`

I'm not sure about your current code - passing `null` as the argument to `removeEventListener`. [My understanding was you had to pass in the function as the second argument.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#matching_event_listeners_for_removal)

Regardless, if you use the `svelte:window` special element, you can entirely remove the `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` calls in `<InfiniteScroll />`. This makes sure that your event listeners are bound correctly, removes the need for the big reactive block in the middle, and is just more "sveltey".

```
<svelte:window bind:scrollY={onScroll} bind:resize={onScroll}/>
```

## Check out the Svelte `{#await}` block

Instead of `$: { fetchData($page.params.slug) }`, you might prefer to do something like the code below. It might save you from initializing components with null-ish/invalid user state. Not specifically related to your post - just noticed you weren't using the feature.

```
{#await fetchData($page.params.slug)}
  <Preloader/>
{:then user}
  <h1 class="text-center font-bold text-xl">
    {user.data.user.full_name || '-'}
  </h1>
  {#key user.data.slug}
    <Feed args={{user_slug: user.data.slug}}/>
  {/key}
{/await}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your help. I was not able to use `<svelte:window />`. The rest was great!